Linux Software RAID MD partition are gone, how to recover?
after a deadly electricity fault we got a Linux MD software raid10 gone.
It seems that all 4 devices cannot see anymore the GPT partition.
The partition was created with this scripts:
parted /dev/sda
parted /dev/sdb
parted /dev/sdc
parted /dev/sdd
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md10 --level raid10 --raid-devices 4 /dev/sd[abcd]1

Now they seems to be completly empty.
How can i recover the partition table?
(It should be a GTP partition table)

You could try "gpart"  it has recovered partition tables for me before.
However I would first run health checks on the drives using "smartctl" and "hdparm"
